# Function overloading in java is not working properly

Tags: java, overloading

I have created one function library in java.I defined two functions in the same class.these functions have same name but different type of arguments

```
public int verifyValueExistsInADFTable(@Arg("sADFTable") String sADFTable,
            @Arg("sValue") String sValue, @Arg("iColumnIndex") int iColumnIndex,
            @Arg("sADFTableName") String sADFTableName) throws Exception {

#this is the first function defined.
public int verifyValueExistsInADFTable(@Arg("sADFTable") String sADFTable,
            @Arg("sValue") String sValue, @Arg("sColumn") String sColumn,
            @Arg("sADFTableName") String sADFTableName) throws Exception {
```

I was able to define these functions. But when i call these functions from the script, it is calling functions randomly. the function differs only in one argument, third one . in one function it is int and another one is string.so even if i call the function with int argument, it is redirecting to the function with string argument.

I am not using any superclass or subclasses .only one class is there

function call from script":

```
`int iRow = cRMService_FuncLibrary.verifyValueExistsInADFTable("{{obj.CRMFunc_Service_OR.ADFTableMassUpdateMRU}}", sFieldValue, 0, "AssignedTo MRU ADF Table");`
```

third argument 0 is int ,still sometimes it is going to function with string argument

Comment: provide calling script please.

Comment: @shivam edited the description

Comment: You need to show us how they are being called. If they are called from multiple places, include all of them.

Comment: @jai int iRow = cRMService_FuncLibrary.verifyValueExistsInADFTable("{{obj.CRMFunc_Service_OR.ADFTableMassUpdateMRU}}", sFieldValue, 0, "AssignedTo MRU ADF Table");  this is the call

Comment: How do you know which method is called? How do you know that the one with the third parameter being a `String` is called? Can you provide a [mcve] that reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: both functions are different.From the info statements in the function was able to make out that it is calling the function with string argument